# Multitouch: ACTION_POINTER_DOWN & ACTION_POINTER_UP

Tags: android, touch, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I'm trying to use multitouch as a method to press 2 things simultaneously.

Here's my Code:

```
TouchHandle.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener () {
              public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                  int actions = event.getActionMasked();
                  switch (actions)
                  {
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                      SendKeyCode(Server, "keydec.down");
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                      SendKeyCode(Server, "keydec.up");
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                  }
              return true;
                  }
        });
```

The problem is that when I touch the screen, the server is retrieving "keydec.down" and "keydec.up" even thought I haven't removed my finger yet from the touchscreen. So the View `TouchHandle` is detecting an `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` and `ACTION_POINTER_UP` when my finger touches the screen even if **I haven't pulled my finger up yet**. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your switch-case implementation seem to lack ``break``s between cases.

Comment: After adding `break` between cases, it now seems to work perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int actions = event.getAction();
switch (actions)
                  {
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                  break;
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                      SendKeyCode(Server, "keydec.down");
                  break;
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                      SendKeyCode(Server, "keydec.up");
                  break;
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  break;

                  }
```

You should use breaks between cases. And i also think that these MotionEvent constants might work with `event.getAction()` try that one.